# Create a new Word document without invoking Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I want to write a VBScript that will create a new Word document in the current directory.  I've tried this sort of thing:

```
Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set document = word.Documents.Add()
document.SaveAs(filename)
```

It basically works, but I want to do it without invoking the Word application.

When I right-click in a File Explorer window, I get a pop-up menu that includes a "New" option from which I can select "Microsoft Word Document".  This creates a new Word document in the current directory without invoking the Word application, and this is the action that I would like to perform in my VBScript.

Does anyone know how I can write that?

As a workaround, my existing VBScript copies an existing blank Word file to the current directory.  This works pretty well.  The one drawback is that the newly created file has the creation time and/or last-modified time of the original file.  How can I "touch" the newly created file (again, without invoking Word) so that it appears to have been created "right now"?

Answer (score 2):

What the *New → Microsoft Word Document* context menu entry does is basically a combination of your workaround and the answer [Robin Mackenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954584/1630171) provided.

New document creation via the Explorer context menu is governed by these registry keys:

- `HKCR\.doc\Word.Document.8\ShellNew` (Word 97/2003 documents)
- `HKCR\.docx\Word.Document.12\ShellNew` (OOXML documents)
- …

If the keys contain a string value `FileName` and the directory `%windir%\ShellNew` contains a file `winword8.doc` (for Word 97/2003 documents) and `winword12.docx` (for OOXML documents) the new document will be created as a copy of that file.

If no matching file exists in `%windir%\ShellNew` or the registry key contains an empty string value `NullFile` instead of the value `FileName`, new files will be created as a zero-length files (basically empty ANSI text file). Word automatically converts these files when opening them.

If the registry key contains neither a value `FileName` nor a value `NullFile` no context menu entry is displayed for the given file type.

If your script just needs to create a new empty document without any particular content or formatting I'd go with the approach Robin suggested. Otherwise stick with your current method of copying a template file.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! To make a long story short, I will have to stick with my original strategy of copying an existing Word file to the desired location, but I need the newly copied file to appear as if it has been just created (rather than retaining the creation/modification date/time of the original file).  In UNIX, I would simply use "touch" to accomplish this, but I don't know how to do it in my VBS script.  Again, I must avoid invoking the Word application.  It seems that I should be able to do this somehow with my file system object.

Comment: This seems to be what I want to accomplish the "touch":
Dim objShell, objFolder // 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") // 
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")) //
objFolder.Items.Item(filename).ModifyDate = Now

Comment: @NoodlesNebula I'd use a [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w.aspx) instance instead of a `Shell.Application` instance.

Comment: I like your idea, Ansgar, but my level of inexperience is such that that I would require more handholding to see exactly how to do it :-)

Comment: Please post a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this which creates an empty text file and changes the extension to .docx. It's not a 'proper' empty `docx` file, but it will open as a blank new Word document.

```
Dim objFSO, strDoc, objFile

' create object to interact with file system
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'name of word doc to create
strDoc = "D:\test.docx"

' create blank file and close
Set objFile = objFSo.CreateTextFile(strDoc)
objFile.Close

' clean up
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Shorter: `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("D:\test.docx")`. Without assigning the file handle to a variable it will be closed automatically. Cleanup happens automatically when execution leaves a context, so `Set foo = Nothing` usually isn't required and just clutters the code. For creating a proper .docx (or understanding why you don't want to do that without Word) see [here](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx).